# Liquibase drop composite key command

Tags: liquibase

How to drop composite key in liquibase using SQL commands ? My composite key doesn't have a name for it.

I tried searching liquibase documentation but it says about primary keys only.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

1. A composite key is a primary key. So if you found a way to drop a primary key, then use it.
2. As you want to use SQL command, not Liquibase XML, JSON etc., then this is a question how to drop a composite key in SQL. An answer depends on a database engine you use. For example in MySQL, you can do that like this:

   ALTER TABLE CITIES DROP PRIMARY KEY;

A primary key from the CITIES table will be deleted even if it is a composite key.
To make it runnable from Liquibase, you just add a comment line with Liquibase meta data. For example:

```
--changeset Harsh:1
ALTER TABLE CITIES DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```